# Bolt-CMS Adding images to the images folder of your theme

Tags: php, html, imagesource, bolt-cms

I am enjoying how much freedom I have in adjusting bolt to fit my own design needs. However,
I was wondering why, when I add new images to the images folder of my theme, it doesn't accept them into the database. Even using the bolt backend it tells me "Uploading to this folder is not allowed."

What I am wanting is to use the initial coding for a slideshow:

```
{% set headerimage = paths.theme ~ "images/" ~ random(theme.headerimage) %}
<img id="headerphoto" src="{{ headerimage }} " alt="" />
```

I removed the initial placeholder images, and included my own into the directory, but it is still looking for the initial images. I deleted and reset the database, but the system is still looking for the initial file.
"
No route found for "GET /theme/Raymond/images/dark-clouds-grass-landscape-405.jpg"
"
Does any one know how I would be allowed to make use of my own images in this directory?

Comment: Please use some code tags.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Bolt still has an old 'config.yml' in your theme folder cached.

Resolve this by clearing the cache in Bolt manually, or updating to the very latest beta version. This is a bug that was fixed last week, I believe.